# Prove that $S \subseteq T$ if, and only if, $S \cup T = T$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $S \subseteq T$ if, and only if, $S \cup T = T$.

I tried to solve this question but it seems confusing, here is what i tried to do:

Suppose $S \subseteq T$, then we need to show that $S \cup T = T$. So since $S \subseteq T$, we know $x \in S$ so $x \in T$ as well, $S \cup T = T$ is true, due to the fact that if $X \in S$ then  $X \in T$,

But I'm not sure about the second part of the proof, I need help.

Comment: You can try a proof by contradiction in the converse direction. What does $S \cup T = T$ and $\neg (S \subseteq T)$ tell you?

Comment: S U T = T, then it can be one case that S = T
and 
¬(S⊆T) tells me that S is not subset of T

Answer (score 2):

If $S \subset T$, then $S \cup T \subset T \cup T = T$; but $T \subset S \cup T$ is trivial.

Conversely, suppose $S \cup T = T$. But then $S \subset S \cup T = T$; hence $S \subset T$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Write what down what $S\cup T\:$means as an explicit set of elements of$\:S\:$and elements of$\:T$.
You can use the same intuition that you used to prove the forward direction to continue from here.